# How to Make a New Subdirectory Under A Specified Parent Directory

Tags: php

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm new to PHP and have been stuck on this for a while.

My application creates a new folder for each 'user.'  My issue is that the new folder just saves directly to the root directory of the project.  I would like the data to save to a 'data' folder within the root.

```
mkdir($user_id);  //creates a folder with the user's name at root directory

mkdir("/path/to/project/data/" . $user_id)  //should create a new folder under a specified directory?
```

What am I missing?  Shouldn't the second code create the folder in the specified directory?  Both lines of the code seem to create username folders at the root directory when run.

Comment: Does `/path/to/project/data/` already exist? `var_dump(file_exists("/path/to/project/data/"))`?

Comment: `/path/to/project/data/` does exist

Comment: Generally I recommend creating a variable or a const representing "the root", something like `DEFINE('PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__)` and using that as a prefix for all file system work. Otherwise, if you start using subfolders to organize your code it can become vague what "the current directory" is. Once you do that, you should be able to use `mkdir(PROJECT_ROOT . '/data/' . $user_id)`

Comment: @ChrisHaas could I get the current root using getcwd() ?

Comment: I made this change but the folder is created in the current working directory regardless.  Despite using the ```mkdir(PROJECT_ROOT . '/data/' . $user_id)```

Comment: When you define `PROJECT_ROOT `, whatever folder that file lives in is what `__DIR__` will be. If you are using subfolders, you might need to define it as `dirname(__DIR__)` or `dirname(__DIR__, 2)` to go up two levels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly comment, but a bit long to fit in the available space.

> mkdir($user_id);  //creates a folder with the user's name at root directory

No it doesn't. Assuming that the string passed as an argument does not contain a directory seperator, it creates a directory in the *current* directory where your code is running. If your code is running in the root directory, your security model is very, *very* broken.

> mkdir("/path/to/project/data/" . $user_id)  //should create a new folder under a specified directory?

Only if /path/to/project/data already exists, is writeable and is a directory. Unless $user_id contains "../../../../.." I think its very unlikely that this will create a directory in /.

> Both lines of the code seem to create username folders at the root directory when run.

You didn't say if your application is accessed via a webserver or is running natively on the system via CLI or as a daemon. Nor did you mention what OS this is on.
If your webserver can modify your root directory then your security is seriously broken and MUST be fixed. If your code is running in the CLI API, then you shouldn't be running it as root / and admin user.

Comment: I'm sorry the code modifies the current directory not the root